# April Fools' Joke background is bugged

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

If you check a website, like, Ask Ubuntu, you have the following background:

[image: Ask Ubuntu]

However, on Code Review, you have the following:

[image: Code Review]

Would be nice if the background was the same, nice, tiled version :(

Comment: It seems to be sized differently for each site - perhaps it's intentional?  BTW, the screenshot on the Meta.SE post shows a unicorn, but I don't see that on any site.  I Want My Unicorn!

Comment: @TobySpeight I fond it. It's actually just a ...corn.

Comment: I got my unicorn - you need a window width of 1401 or wider, in keeping with late 1990s sites that assume particular window sizes...

Comment: In all fairness, they do say '**CAUTION** ~UNDER CONSTRUCTION ~*'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code Review's gargantuan tiles were inherited from the following style rule in the site's theme:

```
body {
    background-size: 280px 503px;
}
```

I guess it's technically fixed now but we won't fix it and we can't reproduce it so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This! I was looking for this. Maybe it will be able to be reproduced in a year?